# Undo and redo features in a Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, undo, undo-redo, redo

I need to make both a <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> function in a Tkinter `Text` widget, so that one may undo and redo things.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tkinter `Text` widget supports undo and redo operations using a stack

At the following link you can find more information:

> http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#more

Otherwise you could look at the tkinter or Tk docs for the `Text` widget and how to create a binding to some keys. The tkinter `Text` widget function you need is `edit_undo`.

Comment: this response is not complete and misses information. one broken link. the link to tkdocs doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 17):

The Tkinter Text widget already supports undo with Control + Z and redo with Shift + Control + Z, but you have to enable them on the widget with `undo=True`.  You might also want to use `autoseparators=True` and `maxundo=-1`.  See this link https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M65.