# Control-Z and Control-Y not working in CustomTkinter TextBox

Tags: python, tkinter, undo, customtkinter, undo-redo

I am using CustomTkinter to make my own application.
I have created a textbox in the program.
It lets me to copy and paste but not to redo or undo.

I have tried solutions online but they are for tkinter and do not work in customtkinter.
My whole point of using customtkinter is for better looking GUIs.
Below is the following code for making a textbox I used.

```
        self.Entry = CTk.CTkTextbox(self, width=816, height=420, font=self.FontList)
        self.Entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Thank You

Vihaan Mody

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of customtkinter? Maybe this is a bug in that library.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I have done that before, but the developer didn't respond. Thank you for  your answer.

Comment: Can it happen that you have to actually enable it, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169344/undo-and-redo-features-in-a-tkinter-text-widget ?

Comment: As the last comment said, you need to enable the feature by adding `undo=1` when creating the textbox.

Comment: @tevemadar
Again, this is customtkinter not tkinter. Thank you for thoughts.

Comment: Hello everyone, I have found how to do undo in the widget. But I couldn't find out how to do redo? Please give me the answer ASAP for my project. Thank you all!!!